# Is doFilter() executed before or after the Servlet's work is done?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

The [javax.servlet.Filter](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) object can be used both for authentication (where the Filter needs to catch the request before any servlet work needs to be done) and for XSLT translation (where the servlet needs to be completely finished generating content). When does it actually get executed?

I know this is implementation dependent (on the web container), but this seems to be problem that needs to be solved by all of them.

Maybe there is a configuration option set somewhere for each Filter registration with the web container?

**Additional:**

Also, what governs the order of Filter execution? Why would FooFilter get executed before BarFilter?

Comment: @Rich:Is doFilter() executed before or after the Servlet’s work is done? > A filter is a program that runs on the server
> before the servlet or JSP page with
> which it is associated.

Comment: The order of filter execution is could be provided in the web.xml file using the <filter-mapping>. Container will intercept program's workflow with the provided filters starting from the top down.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The filter chain in essence wraps the servlet invocation.  The chain will process all links until it hits the "bottom", then allow the servlet to run, and then return up the chain in reverse.  For example, if you have a new "example filter", your doFilter() method may look like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
      ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
      throws IOException, ServletException {
// do pre-servlet work here
chain.doFilter(request, response);
// do post servlet work here

}
```

Comment: This may be a bit contrived, but what if I want to reject the response? In other words, I want to stop the response actually going out? Is this where a ServletException could be thrown?

Comment: Throwing a ServletException would still return a "response" to the client, so it would depend what you meant by not returning a response.  You could create a new response object, with only content you specify and return that if you so chose.

Comment: Ah good point. Absolutely no response isn't really ever desirable. Even when the doFilter() returns before calling chain.doFilter(), it still returns some other error page or default something or other.

Comment: @Jeremy RE: filter order: The order of application of filters is defined by their order of definition in web.xml

Comment: What's the point of "returning up the chain in reverse"?

Answer (score -2):

According to the servlet2.3 specification filter is performed according to web.xml configuration of filter- mapping sequence Ref-http://www.programering.com/a/MTMyADOwATI.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.