# Is there a way to measure Java (Servlet) I/O traffic?

Tags: java, http, servlets, servlet-filters

What I've tried to do is implement a servlet filter with such code:

```
int up = request.getContentLength();
if ( ( (HttpServletRequest) request ).getQueryString() != null )
  {
  up = Math.max( up, ( (HttpServletRequest) request ).getQueryString().length() ) ;
  }
int down = ( (HttpServletResponse) response ).getBufferSize();

processIO( up, down );
```

But, while the up vaue is largely OK, the down value is 8192 for every request.

Any hints appreciated,
Ro

Comment: For the response part you may find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220820/how-to-insert-jsf-page-rendering-time-and-response-size-into-the-page-itself-at/3221516#3221516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getBufferSize()

> Returns the actual buffer size used
>   for the response. If no buffering is
>   used, this method returns 0.

So of course the buffersize never changes! What you want is to get the response and then do size of that. Unfortunately, you can't do that with just HttpServletResponse. But you can implement your own ServletResponse and getContentLength. Make sure you do this after doFilter call.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I can't find a good example at the moment but here is an abstract what you can do. Implement your own response using [wrapper](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) and then for getOutputStream you can instead return your implementation. At the end of your Filter, just get the size of the stream.

Comment: Let me see if i can find a sample for you

Comment: Thanks for the responses ..... Turns out as I already have another GZip Filter, I can just set the bufferSize in that and I have the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

Filters happen before and after the request is handled: [Is doFilter() executed before or after the Servlet's work is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323009/is-dofilter-executed-before-or-after-the-servlets-work-is-done/1323055#1323055).

You must add something like this before `int down = ...`:

```
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

This will invoke servlets (and other filters) that produce reply. Only then you can inspect the reply to see it's size.

Also, you are always getting 8192, because you are asking for a buffer size, not the size of reply.

Here is an example [DumpFilter](http://angelborroy.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/dump-request-and-response-using-javaxservletfilter/) which logs all requests and responses. You can trim it down to just record request and response lengths.

Answer (score 0):

`getBufferSize` returns the buffer size, read [the API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getBufferSize%28%29). I think, you can calculate the down traffic in your code. Just increment a counter when your write to the servlet output stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a request and response and return a wrapped input and output stream accordingly. In those wrapped streams you can track how many bytes been read and written.

This way it would work not only with in-memory buffers, but also with large input and output streamed requests.