# Measuring data going from an application to a server on a remote host

Tags: performance, distributed-computing, traffic-measurement

What is the best way to measure the amount of data going from an application on a local host to a server on a remote host?

I know with something like wireshark you can sniff the data and get a sense of what is transferred, but is there a good way to also measure the size of data exchange over a period of deployment and execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark *will* tell you the size of the data that was transmitted, and it should be easy enough to filter out your conversation.

A simpler solution would be to add logging to your program: simply increment a counter each time you send or receive, and output the counter value periodically.

Another very crude method might be to read your interface statistics, assuming that your process is the only one running on the machine.

Comment: I also found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167639/is-there-a-way-to-measure-java-servlet-i-o-traffic) that specifically talks about how inbound/outbound data can be measured for HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in case of Java applications.