# How to Invoke Servlet and Filter in sequence

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

hi I am working on one web application and facing issue while invoking servelets mentioned in web.xml.

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

     <servlet>
            <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.tpg.fileserver.FileServlet</servlet-class>
     </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
            <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.tpg.fileserver.AuthorizationFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

  </web-app>
```

The issue is that when i m trying to run my application I want the Authroization Filter to run first and then The File Servelet. Right now what is happening is the reverse of what i want. I also tried using 0 for File Servelet but that didnt helped.Below mentioned is my Filter Class code.

```
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter  {

    private static final String kNotAuthorizedUrl = "/NotAuthorized.html";
    private static final String kTrustedHostsFileName = "trusted_hosts.txt";
    private static final String kPublicFilesFileName = "public_files.txt";

    private static final String TRUSTED_HOSTS = "TRUSTED_HOSTS";
    private static final String PUBLIC_FILES = "PUBLIC_FILES";
    private static Properties itsProperties = null;
    public static final String kPropertySingleSignOnURL = "sso-url";
    private static final String kPropertiesFileName = "metadata.properties";
    private static boolean itsInitialized = false;

    private static synchronized void initialize() {
        if (!itsInitialized) {
            try {
                ProductMetadataAPI.setProduct(Version.kProductName, Version.kPhysical);
                System.out.println("Inside Initialize");
                PersistenceAPI.isDebugging = true;
                JNDIConnectionFactory connFactory = new JNDIConnectionFactory("DataSource"); // IDB

                SingleSignOnAuthenticator.setAuthenticationUrl(ConfigurationUtils.getProperties().getProperty(kPropertySingleSignOnURL));

                SecurityAPI.setSecurity(
                    SecurityAPI.makeSecurity(
                        new StandardFactory(),
                        new PersistenceRepository(connFactory),
                        new CommonsBase64Codec(),
                        new SingleSignOnAuthenticator()));

                itsInitialized = true;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                LoggerClass.logErr(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void requestAuthentication(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "BASIC Realm=\"Single Sign-on\"");
        LoggerClass.logInfoMsg("SSO not set. redirecting to siteminder......");
    }


    public void doFilter(ServletRequest inRequest, ServletResponse inResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) inRequest;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) inResponse;
            System.out.println("Before Setting Serervlet Context");
            ConfigurationUtils.setCurrentServletContext(request.getSession().getServletContext());
            System.out.println("After Setting Serervlet Context");
            initialize();

            if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest && (request.getMethod().equals("GET") || request.getMethod().equals("POST"))) {
                String remoteHost = "", authorization = "", userName = "", password = "";
                HttpServletRequest r = (HttpServletRequest)request;
                Enumeration<String> e = r.getHeaderNames();
                while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String headerName = e.nextElement();
                    LoggerClass.logInfoMsg(headerName + "=" + r.getHeader(headerName));
                }
                LoggerClass.logDebugMsg("Proxy-Client-IP is :" + r.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP"));
                LoggerClass.logDebugMsg("Remote-Address-IP is :" + r.getRemoteAddr());


                remoteHost = r.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
                if (remoteHost == null) {
                    remoteHost = r.getRemoteAddr();
                    LoggerClass.logDebugMsg("Remote-Address-IP ["+remoteHost + "] is requesting " + r.getRequestURI());
                }else{
                    LoggerClass.logDebugMsg("Proxy-Client-IP ["+remoteHost + "] is requesting " + r.getRequestURI());
                }

                authorization = r.getHeader("Authorization");
                if (authorization != null) {
                    final int index = authorization.indexOf(' ');
                    if (index > 0) {
                        final String[] credentials = StringUtils.split(new String(Base64.decodeBase64(authorization.substring(index))), ':');

                        if (credentials.length == 2) {
                            userName = credentials[0].toUpperCase();
                            password = credentials[1];
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isSiteminderAuthenticationPresent(r)) {
                    LoggerClass.logInfoMsg("Inside Siteminder Logic ......");
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    return;
                } else if (isPublic(request) || isTrusted(remoteHost)) {
                    LoggerClass.logInfoMsg("Inside Public/Trusted Host Logic ......");
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    return;
                } else if (!isBasicAuthenticationPresent(userName, password)) {
                    LoggerClass.logInfoMsg("Failed in Basic Authentication Present.....");
                    requestAuthentication(response);
                } else if (!isBasicAuthenticationValid(r.getSession(), userName, password)) {
                    LoggerClass.logInfoMsg("Failed in Basic Authentication Validation.....");
                    requestAuthentication(response);
                } else {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            }
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + kNotAuthorizedUrl);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LoggerClass.logErr(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Below mentioned is my Servlet Partial Code :

```
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet
{
public FileServlet()
    {
         System.out.println("In fileServlet");
         this.itsRootDir = Common.getRequiredProperty(Common.kPropertyRootDir);
            // some business logic
    }
@Override public void doGet(HttpServletRequest inRequest, HttpServletResponse inResponse)
    throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String theRelFileName = Common.extractFileName(inRequest, false);
        String theFileName = this.itsRootDir + theRelFileName;
        File theFile = new File(theFileName);
     //Some more Business Logic
}
}
```

Below present are the Sysout logs I got in application logs. Here I noticed one strange thing. First the call is going to File Servlet, Then Authorization Filter and then again to File Servlet.

```
[8/8/14 0:54:05:109 EDT] 0000002b SystemOut     O In fileServlet
[8/8/14 0:54:05:161 EDT] 0000002b SystemOut     O In Authoriazation Filter
[8/8/14 0:54:05:232 EDT] 0000002b SystemOut     O In fileServlet
```

Comment: What does the `AuthorizationFilter` do? Show us.

Comment: Filters wrap Servlets. they can be used for both pre and post Servlet invocation - could you post your Filter code as I suspect that may be where your issues is. See this related post for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323009/is-dofilter-executed-before-or-after-the-servlets-work-is-done

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Authroization fileter is taking request and authenticating the user. Thats the first step I want to be in my application. It is also setting the servlet context which I would be needing in File Servlet.Therefore I need File Servlet to be invoked after AuthorizationFilter.

Comment: @Romski: Thats Exactly what I want. I have a do Filter method in AuthorizationFilter Class but somehow FileServlet is invoking first.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Implementation Added.

Comment: @Romski: Filter Implementation Added.

Comment: Better try with sample to invoke Filter then go further.Because of the logs of check you have done be failed so it goes to invoke the Servlet.

Comment: Right, please show evidence of the results you are seeing. How can you tell the Filter acts _after_ the Servlet?

Comment: In the application Logs i am seeing the sysout statements of File Servlet first which I have put in the both the classes.

Comment: Post relevant parts of your `Servlet`. Restart your server, send a single request that includes the `Servlet`. Post the logs.

Comment: what you can do is change the `url pattern of servlet`. I mean first when the user enters some url pattern like `/*` redirect to `filter class` and if he authenticates successfully then redirect to `servlet` or else redirect to `error` page.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: added the servlet partial code and logs.

Comment: That log is in a constructor. It will be called once. It is not part of the request-response cycle.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that the servlet mapping and filter mapping are using the same URL pattern.  It's not a good idea to map wildcards to a filter without a specific reason to do so.

Also, don't put `synchronized` methods in your `doFilter` method, as it will cause performance problems.

Comment: @Brad: Hi.. Right now I am trying to deploy this application on Websphere Application server. It was working properly with this same configuration on Weblogic Server but on Websphere application it is giving problems. So my question is that does this behaviour differ for different application server ?

Comment: For WAS?  Yes, those features can differ.  WebSphere has some vendor-specific quirks, not all of which are documented.

Comment: Also, I made a mistake in my comment - you shouldn't map a servlet to a wildcard without a specific reason (like, for example, extracting parameters from the path).  It's OK to do that with filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for the above mentioned issue was that the constructor present in FileServlet was invoking before the filter was executed. To solve this problem I have changed the constructor to a public method which is being called in doget() method of Servlet. After this changed the filter was invoking first and then the servlet was being invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The `filters` are always initialized during `webapp's` startup in the order as they are definied in `web.xml`.

The `servlets` are by default initialized during the first HTTP request on their `url-pattern` only.

So in this case first The webapp's `web.xml` will be parsed and every `Filter` found in `web.xml` will be created once and kept in `server's memory`

Now when a request comes from url pattern like `/*` the container looks for the pattern finds the mapping for `servlet` so initializes the `servlet`. Then to process the request the `filter` gets invoked.

To solve this you can change the url pattern of servlet.When the user enters some url pattern like `/*` redirect to filter class and if he authenticates successfully then redirect to servlet specified with some other `url pattern` or else redirect to `error page`

Comment: hi.. Right now I am trying to deploy this application on Websphere server. It was working properly with this same configuration on Weblogic Server but on Websphere application it is giving problems. So my question is that does this behaviour differ for different application server ?